# Nullstellensatz: If $V(f)=V(g)$ we have that $Rad \langle f \rangle =Rad \langle g \rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

In my lecture notes I have the following:

From the Nullstellensatz (NSS for short) we have the following:

$$\text{ If } V(f)=V(g) \Rightarrow V(Rad(\langle f \rangle ))=V(Rad \langle g \rangle ) \overset{ \text{ NSS } }{ \Longrightarrow } Rad \langle  f \rangle =Rad \langle g \rangle $$

Can you explain it to me? I haven't understood it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Nullstellensatz* says that $I(V(f)) = \sqrt{(f)}$, so $V(f) = V(g)$ implies (applying $I$ on both sides) that $\sqrt{(f)} = \sqrt{(g)}$, where I note $\sqrt{J}$ the radical of an ideal $J$.

Comment: For a commutative ring $A$ with unit, recall that $V(f)$ is the set of primes ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ of $A$ such that $f\not\in \mathfrak{p}$, and that if $X$ is a subset of $\textrm{Spec}(A)$ (set of all prime ideals of $A$) then $I(X)$ is the set of $f\in A$ such that for each $\mathfrak{p}\in X$, the image of $f$ in the residue field $k(\mathfrak{p})$ of $A$ at $\mathfrak{p}$ is zero. This relies on the fact that for any commutative ring $A$ with unit, $\sqrt{(0)} = \cap_{\mathfrak{p}\in\textrm{Spec}(A)} \mathfrak{p}$.

Comment: Proof of $\sqrt{(0)} = \cap_{\mathfrak{p}\in\textrm{Spec}(A)} \mathfrak{p}$. The inclusion $\subseteq$ is trivial, by definition of a prime ideal. To show the opposite inclusion, let's $a\in A$ be non nilpotent. Then the localization $A_{(a)}$ is non-zero and has therefore (Zorn) a prime (in fact maximal) ideal $\mathfrak{P}$. The inverse image $\mathfrak{p}$ of $\mathfrak{P}$ in $A$ is then a prime ideal (general, primality of ideal is stable by inverse image by a morphism) not containing $a$, so that our $\mathfrak{p}$ is not in $\cap_{\mathfrak{p}\in\textrm{Spec}(A)} \mathfrak{p}$.

Comment: $\sqrt{(0)} = \cap_{\mathfrak{p}\in\textrm{Spec}(A)} \mathfrak{p}$ for any (commutative with unit) $A$ implies $\sqrt{(I)} = \cap_{\mathfrak{p}\in\textrm{Spec}(A), I\subseteq \mathfrak{p}} \mathfrak{p}$. Indeed, just write $\sqrt{(0)} = \cap_{\mathfrak{p}\in\textrm{Spec}(B)} \mathfrak{p}$ for $B = A/I$.